# How to register and start a new IBackgroundTask from a IBackgroundTask?

Tags: windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I have an IBackgroundTask that needs to spin up other backgroundtasks.

```
<Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="IoT.TestDrive.StartupTask">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <iot:Task Type="startup" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
```

This code works:

```
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var def = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        try
        {
            TimeTrigger trigger = new TimeTrigger(15, false);
            BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
            builder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(SubTask).FullName;
            builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
            BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            def.Complete();
        }
    }

}
```

But it does not trigger immediate, and that's what I want.
Any suggestions here?

Comment: How do you "spin up"? You register a background task(SubTask) in IoT.TestDrive.StartupTask?

Comment: Yes. I updated the post with a little more code to show this.